# With List of Lists: How to Make Third Element a Float Data Type With sort() function

Tags: python, list, sorting, key

I have the following list of lists:

```
list_of_lists = [['43', 'Yellowjackets', '98.6'], ['10', 'Book of Bobba Fett', '32.245'], ['132', 'And Just Like That', '77.014'], ['2', 'Sex & The City', '4.732']]
```

I want to change the 3rd element (index=2) of each individual list from string to a float.  For example, in the first list I want ['43', 'Yellowjackets', **98.6**]

But here's the tricky part... I want to change the string to float within my sort() function.  My current sort function stands as:

```
list_of_lists .sort(key=float(lambda x:x[2]))
```

But I get the following error:
[image]

Comment: `list_of_lists .sort(key=lambda x: float(x[2]))`

Comment: After the sort, should `list_of_lists[0][2]` be a float?

Comment: I believe you cannot. `sort` uses its `key` argument internally to change the list order not its content, the solution would be to use a simple list comprehension to change each value of the list and then `sort` it

Comment: The answer is "no".  The sole purpose of the key function is for sorting.  It doesn't affect the original value in any way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the type of the third elements before sorting, then you can use list comprehension and then sort.

```
list_of_lists[:] = [sublist[:2] + [float(sublist[2])] for sublist in list_of_lists]
list_of_lists.sort(key=lambda x:x[2])
print(list_of_lists)
```

Output:

```
[['2', 'Sex & The City', 4.732],
 ['10', 'Book of Bobba Fett', 32.245],
 ['132', 'And Just Like That', 77.014],
 ['43', 'Yellowjackets', 98.6]]
```

But if you only want the `sort` method to see the third elements as floats, then you can use `float` function in lambda:

```
list_of_lists.sort(key=lambda x: float(x[2]))
print(list_of_lists)
```

Output:

```
[['2', 'Sex & The City', '4.732'],
 ['10', 'Book of Bobba Fett', '32.245'],
 ['132', 'And Just Like That', '77.014'],
 ['43', 'Yellowjackets', '98.6']]
```